# what does "/=" mean in objective c

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void) reduce{
    int u = numerator;
    int v = denominator;
    int temp;



    while (v != 0) {
        temp = u % v;
        u = v;
        v = temp;
    }

    numerator /= u;
    denominator /= u;

}
```

I am currently starting to learn objective c and was just wondering what this bit of the code actually does?

```
numerator /= u;
denominator /= u;
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: its a shortcut for numerator=numerator/u;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a /= b` is the same thing as `a = a / b`. It's just shorthand notation, just like `+=`, `&=`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It's a shorthand operator for divide then assign.

The long version is :

```
numerator = numerator  / u;
```

Other similar operators are `+=`, `*=`, `-=`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Its a short form of

```
numerator = numerator / u;
denominator = denominator / u;
```

Answer (score 1):

It like int a += 1, but divide instead of plus. :)